# Category save issue after upgrade - M2

Tags: magento2, category, save

Getting this "**A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.**" error after category save.

I have try to disable all custom modules form app/code directory but still category save functionality isn't working.

Not getting any help from log file and ini_set('display_errors', 1);

On category save getting this **404 page not found error** error in network tab in browser, for this request "**{{base url}}catalog/category/validate/?isAjax=true**"

**Note:** Getting this issue only for few categories.

Thanks.

Comment: Any error in log files?

Comment: Not showing any error in log file.